# NGINX HTTPS - SSL Certificates

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

I have three files regarding certificates:

```
- example.com.ca-bundle # contains root and intermediate certificates
- example.com.crt # Certificate
- example.com.p7b # only contains certificates and chain certificates
```

I need to configure NGINX to accept HTTPS, but I feel a bit confused as I do not have the most experience with SSL, and most examples seem to use a certificate/key pair. Would this NGINX configuration be the correct approach?

```
server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate     /path/to/example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/example.com.crt;
    ...
}
```

Comment: You need to have the private key. It should have been created before you created the CSR. If you don't have the private key you cannot create a HTTPS server.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich is correct. If you do not have your private key you will need to generate one and another CSR. Your formatting otherwise looks correct but you'll want to change `ssl_certificate_key` to use the private key file after you get it and not the certificate.

Also you'll want to append the contents of the ca-bundle file on to the crt file to ensure your certificate is trusted by browsers.

Comment: Thank you, guys! This answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

Like others pointed out in the comments you need to use the private key for ssl_certificate_key. If it helps further, below is an excerpt from an Nginx configuration using Let's Encrypt SSL certificates. In some cases cert.pem is not enough and chain.pem is also needed for compatibility across more browsers and server types.

```
    # Full chain fullchain.pem is just a concatenation of public key cert.pem and chain.pem. If you are using certbot this will be automatically created.
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/fullchain.pem;
 
    # Like others pointed out in the comments there should be a private key and not the cert file
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/privkey.pem;
```

You can use certbot (a tool by Let's Encrypt) to automate the generation of your certificates. Here is a link with [Step by Step instructions for automating HTTPS / SSL Certificate setup for your Nginx Hosted Website](https://www.taggedweb.com/blog/posts/http-to-https-add-an-ssl-certificate-to-your-nginx-hosted-website-with-lets-encrypt)